# Function is producing Mismatch error. Don't know why changing variable names solved it

Tags: excel, vba, syntax-error

The Primary function calling Day1WeekNum & Day1inMonth

```
Function NthDay(Date1)
' Tells you if a date is the 3rd Tuesday of the Month
Dim Day1Name, Day1WeekNum, A, B, DayName, Nth
Dim Status ' Tells you if there is anything in the rest of the Array
Dim cWeekNum ' Number for the current week
Dim WeekDiff 'Difference between the week numbers
Dim cDayNum   'Number for the day of the week for Date1
Dim Week1Num

Week1Num = Day1WeekNum(Date1) ' tells me the week number of the first day of the month
Day1Name = Day1inMonth(Date1) ' tell me the day of the week for the first day of the month
```

Code for Day1inMonth

```
Function Day1inMonth(Date1)
'Tells you the weekday of the first day in a month of the provided date
Dim cYear, cMonth, month1st, day1


cYear = Year(Date1)
cMonth = Month(Date1)
month1st = DateSerial(cYear, cMonth, 1)
day1 = Weekday(month1st, vbSunday)

Day1inMonth = day1
End Function
```

Code for Day1WeekNum

```
Function Day1WeekNum(Date1 As Date)
'Tells you the week of the first day of the month of the provided date
Dim cYear, cMonth, day1Week
Dim month1st As Date

cYear = Year(Date1)
cMonth = Month(Date1)
month1st = DateSerial(cYear, cMonth, 1)
day1Week = WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(month1st, 1)

Day1WeekNum = day1Week
End Function
```

I had to change the code above to the code below in order to stop a mismatch error. I don't know why. Does it have to relate to variable scope or something else? I'm trying to understand so I can avoid the reason for the error in the future.

New code that allowed it to work:

```
Function Day2WeekNum(Date1)
'Tells you the week of the first day of the month of the provided date

Dim cYear1, cMonth1, day1Week1
Dim month1st1 As Date

cYear1 = Year(Date1)
cMonth1 = Month(Date1)
month1st1 = DateSerial(cYear, cMonth, 1)
day1Week1 = WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(month1st, 1)

Day2WeekNum = day1Week1
End Function
```

Comment: A) Which line gives you the mismatch error?  B) Why are you not assigning a Type to any of those variable? `Dim cYear As Long, cMonth As Long, dayWeek1 As Long`

Comment: @BigBen,The function Day1WeekNum throws the error before it gets into the function. So as soon as NthDay get to the line with Day1WeekNum .

Comment: @user3431106 In `Day2WeekNum()` you're using `month1st` for `day1Week1`, which should be out of scope. Not sure how you're getting any result there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have both a local variable and a function in scope which have the same name - `Day1WeekNum`

The local variable is implicitly a Variant because it hasn't been declared as being of any specific type. Variants can contain arrays as well as individual (scalar) values.

The assignment `Week1Num = Day1WeekNum(Date1)` looks like a function call but is actually trying to access an array. No array has been defined so you get a type mismatch error. If you give the `Week1Num` variable an explicit non-array/non-Variant type then the error will change to "Compile error: expected array".

Changing the function name worked because the new function name didn't match any local variables in the calling procedure. To avoid this issue in future:

- use `Option Explicit` at the top of each module (by turning on
  "Require Variable Declaration" in Tools > Options > Editor in the VBA
  editor)
- give every variable an explicit type - e.g. `Dim Day1WeekNum As Integer`
- avoid declaring variables which have the same name as a sub or function that is in scope because this can be confusing and lead to issues

Comment: @barrowc, Now I see the need for declaring variable. But what about the code leads it to think it is trying to access an array?